# How can I enable PMONs from a user program in Linux?

Tags: linux

PMONs are enabled using MSRs.  MSRs are accessible only from ring 0.  Is there any API to enable PMONs in Linux from user space?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you're looking for is called "oprofile" on Linux. You can enable it from userspace, but it requires root access.

http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

perfctr api allows this: http://www.ale.csce.kyushu-u.ac.jp/~satoshi/how_to_use_perfctr.htm

PAPI is another API. http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) tool. It's a userspace tool for accessing the Linux kernel's perf_event API.

If you want to do the syscalls yourself, use perf_event syscalls, which are poorly documented as of May 2016. Check out the [Unofficial Documentation](http://web.eece.maine.edu/~vweaver/projects/perf_events/), or the kernel source itself. The kernel source is guaranteed to be "correct" documentation, but, unfortunately, inscrutable.